# Powershell script executed by SQL Server doesn't take effect

Tags: sql-server, permissions, powershell, xp-cmdshell

I'm doing some testing and I want to execute a PowerShell script through xp_cmdshell. Below is the PowerShell script (`c:\temp\sqltotext.ps1`).

```
echo "haha" | Out-File "c:\temp\haha.txt"
```

Then I execute the script through `xp_cmdshell` like this.

```
DECLARE @result INT;
EXEC @result = sys.xp_cmdshell N'powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs ''-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File c:\temp\sqltotext.ps1''"';
IF (@result = 0) PRINT 'Success';
ELSE PRINT 'Failure';
```

It runs successfully and I can find the file `c:\temp\haha.txt` with the content `haha`.

However, when I change the content of `c:\temp\sqltotext.ps1` to:

```
echo Process CurrentUser LocalMachine | %{Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass -Force -Scope $_}
```

and execute the same aforementioned TSQL command, the TSQL reports success but I didn't get the expected result (the execution policy in all scopes were NOT changed).

When I execute the PowerShell script manually (in a PowerShell console and type `c:\temp>.\sqltotext.ps1`), it works as expected (the execution policy in all scopes were changed). Why this happens?

I did some investigation though. `EXEC xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe'` reports I'm running with `nt service\mssqlserver`. I also manually added `nt service\mssqlserver` into the `administrators` local user group. By using process explorer, I can confirm the PowerShell session indeed was started and all related processes have admin permission (Integrity = High).

[image]

The cmd.exe command line looks like this:

[image]

When I execute this command manually, it can change the execution policy without any issue (I changed all execution policy back to the original values after this).

[image]

The PowerShell process command line looks like this:

[image]

When I execute the PowerShell process command line manually, I can change the execution policies too. I don't have any idea why when I run the command through `xp_cmdshell`, it doesn't change anything.

BTW, I know there are multiple ways to write the command. I'm just talking about the technical skills here, so please don't suggest me changing command syntax etc.

Comment: Do you plan to run this from a stored procedure, interactively or as a SQL Agent job?  xp_cmdshell can open so many security holes that you really need to use it with the utmost caution.  If you are planning to use SQL Agent then make use of the proxy and create a local Windows user that has only the limited permissions needed and create the crdential for this to use by the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

`xp_cmdshell` is not PowerShell.

If you run: `xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe';` you will discover that you are `nt service\mssqlserver` and not `Administrator`.

[image]

`xp_cmdshell` is impersonating that user (which is a service in our case).
So the solution of the problem should be to impersonate an Administrator.

But you cannot do that.

I have tried using [Proxy Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-xp-cmdshell-proxy-account-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'ADVWKS\Max04', 'ds35efg##65';  
GO
```

But I couldn't impersonate `Administrator`.

I have also tried adding this code at the beginning of the script:

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }
```

But the code just run forever because is expecting you to click on the YES and impersonate the `Administrator`.

I have also tried to run it from an Agent job: no joy.

[This guide](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2143/creating-a-sql-server-proxy-account-to-run-xpcmdshell/) says not to impersonate a domain Admin. Which is exactly what you want to do. I let you try that because I cannot do that on my PC.

For start debugging try to run [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/270611/sudo-equivalent-in-powershell):

```
runas /user:domain\administrator $^
```

and check if you can **at least be Administrator** on that machine.
So the recipe is:

1. Try to impersonate Administrator and execute the .ps1 script from command line
2. In alternative add a user with Administrator privileges
3. Impersonate it through SSMS

Good luck.

Comment: That proves the powershell script didn't take effect. The script is assumed to change execution policies to `bypass`. From your screenshot it's all default values. It's exactly the same behavior as I observed in my environment.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your answer! You can use `echo Process CurrentUser LocalMachine | %{Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned -Force -Scope $_}` to change execution policies to remotesigned. Change `remotesigned` to whatever execution policy you want. Btw, `Undefined` is not a valid execution policy. It's the initial default value and just means you never manually set execution policy. Set all to `remotesigned` is a pretty safe value.

Comment: @Justalearner, I tried as much as I could. There's not much I can do from here. Try the last guide as I cannot reproduce it on my PC

Comment: @Justalearner, cannot stop thinking about this. I believe we are doing this wrong. PowerShell has to be executed by PowerShell. Just curious: what is your ultimate goal? What is the PS script supposed to do?

Comment: haha, actually, as you can see, it's a way to execute a PowerShell script through xp_cmdshell. I just came across some cases that this technique doesn't work. After some investigation I found it indeed doesn't work sometimes. I just want to know where is the root of the problem.

Comment: When you discover xp_cmdshell the tendency is to keep going and do a lot of suff with that. I created a query for calling API endpoints and save data directly to SQL Server:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067593/calling-an-api-from-sql-server-stored-procedure/52686957 . Then one day your mania will stop.